# Products of Symmetric Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to find an example of two matrices A and B such that AB is invertible, 
but A and B are not. I have an example for the singular 1x1 matrix, because I can 
take $A=(1,0)$ and $B=(1,0)^T$. Then $AB=(1)$, which is invertible, but

$$BA=
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

and this matrix is not invertible. I was hoping to find an example for higher 
dimension matrices, like $2\times 2$ or $3 \times 3$. Thank you!

Comment: So, should $A$ and $B$ be not invertible, or $BA$?

Comment: Are you looking for matrices A and B such that AB us invertible but BA is not or for matrices A,B such that AB is invertible but A and B are not invertible?

Comment: If a matrix is not square, it doesn't make sense to ask whether it is *invertible*.  Not that the rank of $AB$ is less than or equal to the minimum of rank($A$) and rank($B$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose 
$A=
\begin{bmatrix}
 2 & 0 &0 \\
 0 & 2 & 0
\end{bmatrix},
B=\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 0  \\
 0 & 1  \\
 0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}$

Then $AB$ is invertible, but $A,B$ are not invertible. 
You can't have $AB$ and $BA$ both are invertible while $A,B$ both are not invertible since $rank(AB) \leq \min(rank(A),rank(B)$. For square matrix, $det(A)det(B） = det(AB)$ so you can't have square matrices as your example.